# Can I write v-v=O and also v-v=0

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, vector-fields

Define **v** as a vector in $K^n$.

Can I write **v**-**v**=**O** and also **v**-**v**=0?

Where **O** is the zero vector and 0 is a scalar.

Can't seem to find this anywhere..

Comment: No, if $v\in K^n$ is a vector then $v-v$ is the zero vector, not the zero scalar. This just stems from the fact that the subtraction operation between two vectors maps two vectors to another vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically $\vec{v}-\vec{v}$ is the zero vector. The notational distinction is sometimes not made between the zero vector and the zero scalar because $0\vec{v} = \vec{0}$ for any vector $\vec{v}$.

Comment: 0v=O, yeah, that's where my confusion was coming from.

Comment: If you think I sufficiently answered your question then it would be appropriate to accept the answer.

Comment: yeah i will, just gotta wait 2 minutes mate

Comment: Gotcha, I just mention this because some relatively new users often aren't aware of the feature.